# What is the correct way to check an object's type in a conditional statement - python

Tags: python, debugging, types, pycharm, conditional-statements

What is the correct way to check an object's type in a conditional statement?

Edit: It seems I have misdiagnosed the issue. My conditional statement did not trigger because the json.dumps code did not work like I thought it did. Even though the error message said `o.__class__.name` is `int64`, it never actually has that value until the error is raised (I checked through step-by-step debugging). How it *does* work, I do not quite know, and is a subject for another day. I'll put an answer to the question below.

I could solve the issue I had by following Lenik's advice below.

Background:

When executing

```
from json import dumps
json.dumps(vars(my_object))
```

I get an error

```
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\json\encoder.py", line 180, in 
  default    o.__class__.__name__)
TypeError: Object of type 'int64' is not JSON serializable
```

error when using `json.dumps` in python, after running code where I make use of the `vars` statement to convert some objects into a dictionary.

I conclude that somewhere in the object I am using a numpy `int64` rather than the standard python `int`, and that this is causing the error.

Problem is that my_object has quite a lot of layers and places to look.

So I thought the clever thing would be to put a conditional breakpoint (I can do this in PyCharm) in line 180 of `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\json\encoder.py` with the condition being

```
 o.__class__.__name__ == "int64"
```

Then I can run the code in debug mode and hopefully find the offending layer/variable.

I've tried it, as well as in a few points call-stack in-between my `dumps` call and the lowest point in the call stack, but my breakpoint is never triggered.

I am therefore suspecting I am not using the correct conditional statement to check the name of the object being serialized... ?

Hence my question:
What is the correct way to check an object's type in a conditional statement?

Here is the object that is causing the trouble:

```
[  
   {  
      "combat_id":null,
      "units":[  
         {  
            "unit_id":7,
            "engagements":{  
               "front":[  
                  8,
                  -20,
                  -20
               ],
               "left":[  

               ],
               "right":[  

               ],
               "rear":[  

               ]
            }
         },
         {  
            "unit_id":8,
            "engagements":{  
               "front":[  
                  7,
                  -20,
                  80
               ],
               "left":[  

               ],
               "right":[  

               ],
               "rear":[  

               ]
            }
         }
      ],
      "combat_log":{  
         "combat_id":null,
         "full_log":[  
            [  
               {  
                  "initiative_step":"asf",
                  "_load_printables":true,
                  "striker_names":[  
                     "Pieka's Spear Boys",
                     "Coert's Pennyless Pokers"
                  ],
                  "striker_descs":[  
                     "High Elf Core Infantry",
                     "High Elf Core Infantry"
                  ],
                  "striker_players":[  
                     "Pieka",
                     "Coert"
                  ],
                  "striker_qtys":[  
                     25,
                     21
                  ],
                  "target_names":[  
                     "Coert's Pennyless Pokers",
                     "Pieka's Spear Boys"
                  ],
                  "target_descs":[  
                     "High Elf Core Infantry",
                     "High Elf Core Infantry"
                  ],
                  "target_players":[  
                     "Coert",
                     "Pieka"
                  ],
                  "target_qtys":[  
                     21,
                     25
                  ],
                  "attack_types":[  
                     "melee",
                     "melee"
                  ],
                  "attacks":[  
                     20,
                     21
                  ],
                  "to_hit_dcs":[  
                     4,
                     4
                  ],
                  "hits":[  
                     10,
                     10
                  ],
                  "to_wound_dcs":[  
                     4,
                     4
                  ],
                  "savable_wounds":[  
                     5,
                     5
                  ],
                  "armor_dcs":[  
                     5,
                     5
                  ],
                  "armor_saves":[  
                     1,
                     1
                  ],
                  "ward_dcs":[  
                     7,
                     7
                  ],
                  "ward_saves":[  
                     0,
                     0
                  ],
                  "unsaved_wounds":[  
                     4,
                     4
                  ],
                  "remaining_wounds":[  
                     17,
                     21
                  ],
                  "input":[  
                     ""
                  ],
                  "printables":[  
                     "<dominus_core.objects.sub_classes.combat.init_step_log.PrintableEntry object at 0x000000000EA72B70>",
                     "<dominus_core.objects.sub_classes.combat.init_step_log.PrintableEntry object at 0x000000000EA92C88>"
                  ],
                  "printable_strings":[  

                  ],
                  "longest_name":1,
                  "_longest_name":28
               }
            ]
         ],
         "easy_log":[  

         ]
      }
   }
]
```

Comment: try `type(variable)` and will return the type

Comment: Thanks @KostadinSlavov. I tried `type(o) == int64`, but also this did not trigger the breakpoint.

Comment: show me your object

Comment: @KostadinSlavov, Ok, I added it to the OP. It is probably the non-serialized `PrintableEntry` objects (near the bottom) that is causing the pain. Since we've already established two ways to test for type (but they do not solved my problem), I'm going to change the angle of the question also.

Comment: OK when I'm back from the store if still not answered I'll find the solution

Comment: Thanks! What I'm doing in the meantime is to write a `__dict__` method for "full_log" which returns `[vars(i) for i in self.printables]` rather than the actual `PrintableEntry` object itself .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create a serializer for the objects that are not recognised by standard json serializer:

```
def my_json_serializer(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, int64):
        return int(obj)    # or whatever other conversion you'd prefer
    raise TypeError ("Type %s not serializable" % type(obj))
```

then use it like this:

```
json.dumps( vars(my_object), default=my_json_serializer)
```

Comment: Thanks - that's a very elegant solution.
Indeed this does point to the `PrintableEntry` object that I suspected (see comments on question). Since `PrintableEntry` is actually quite serializable, I should be able to solve this be adding an `elif type(obj) == PrintableEntry': return vars(obj)`.

Comment: @levraininjaneer sure, knock yourself out with the additional `elif` statements =)

Comment: Ah, and by taking away the int64 clause, I could find where that value was hiding! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Both

```
my_object.__class__.__name__ == "int64"
```

and

```
type(my_object) == int64
```

are valid ways to check for type.

As stated in the question Edit, I misunderstood my problem.

Comment: If anyone is interested in explaining how json.dumps actually does work and why the `type(o) == int64` is never actually triggered, I'd be very grateful.